# Way to see if a method of an abstract class is not overridden by one of the extending classes

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I have a abstract class , let's say `AbstractClass` and multiple other classes (700+) extending that abstract class. `AbstractClass` has a method, let's say `baseMethod()` which is not an abstract method. Many classes(500+) override that method and have their own implementation. Now with eclipse I can easily see the ones that override that method by doing `Ctrl+Shift+G`, but is there a way other than manually, to see the classes that don't override that method `baseMethod()` ( the remaining 200 ) but is a class extending `AbstractClass`.

Comment: 700 classes extending an abstract class? Yikes.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Such is the codebase. :(

Comment: Maybe a little regex search to find every file that has `extends AbstractClass` and doesn't have `baseMethod() {`.

Comment: @Gabriel : That is also a great idea. I'll give it a try. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could make the method temporary as `abstract` and see the error outputs.

Comment: Wow this is a great idea, but eclipse won't show the classes as error when I changed the method as `abstract` so I still have to see the class manually if it's has error or not. I rebuilt the project couple of times but still not working. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: @stackFan try to run the project

Comment: Thanks man! You made it so simple for something that could have been so tedious.